# Change what fields are copied when copying an account in Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, user-accounts

I've noticed that all of the address with the exception of the street address is copied when copying an Active Directory user account. Is there a way to change this? We're currently running a 2003 AD on 2008 DCs and will eventually upgrade the domain level when we activate our new exchange server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have an attribute be included in a copy, you must modify the schema for that attribute - always be very, very careful with schema modifications.

Find the attributeSchema object for the attribute you want to modify in the Schema partition (ADSIEdit is probably the simplest tool to accomplish this), and modify its `searchFlags` attribute.

It's a bit field, the `0x10` bit is what you'll want to set without modifying what's already there.  Verify that the flag isn't already set (if it is, then you'll unintentionally turn off copying and turn on tuple indexing - if you're not familiar with bit fields, do a bit of [light reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) first), then add 16 to the integer value in the attribute to enable copying.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something related to the schema, which I don't think I'll be editing, but it's nice to know how to do it if it ever bothers me enough. :)